# Tengo los datos almacenados en Firebase ¿Cómo puedo dejar sin efecto los cambios realizados en una actividad cuando dicha actividad se cierra?

Tags: firebase

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android Studio(java)  con base de datos en Firebase(RealTime Database). He desarrollado un código de consulta y registro en Firebase en una actividad, pero quisiera que al cerrar la actividad ese registro se anule automáticamente sin necesidad de usar algún botón.
¿Se podrá implementar algún método o código que me permita lograr el objetivo?

Agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.